# How can I breake my javaScript code into multiple files?

Tags: javascript, oop, scope

my application uses this main object, as you see most of the job is done in this method. the problem is that this object will get too big if I want to write it all in one file. and the code is gonna be hard to debug. is there any way that I can use to split this object into multiple files (like each function in one file)? 
I also want to be able to access and change displayArray, userOptions and query variables from those functions.
any kinds of advice is appreciated. thank :)

```
application = {
    displayArray : new Array(),
    userOptions : new Array(),
    query : '', 
    status : false,

    initilize : function () {
        //its going to initialize displayArray, userOptions and status.
    },

    loadOptions : function () {
        //this function builds userOptions array
    },

    JSONConverter : function () {
      //this function uses query to builds displayArray  
    },

    display : function () {
       //this function will use displayArray to build HTML elements on page
    },

};
```

Answer (score 1):

For example:

```
 // file: application.js
(function (window, undefined) {
  var application = {
     // ...
  };
  window['application'] = application;
}(window));

// file: application-module1.js
(function (application, window, undefined) {
  var module_foo = {
     // ...
  };
  application['module_foo'] = module_foo;
}(application, window));

// file: application-module2.js
(function (application, window, undefined) {
  var module_bar = {
     // ...
  };
  application['module_bar'] = module_bar;
}(application, window));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can! Write several .js scripts, then embed them in the html file like this:

```
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="script1.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="script2.js"></script>
</head>
```

[This](http://snap.berkeley.edu/snapsource/snap.html) is a good example of how to do it. ([source](http://snap.berkeley.edu/snapsource/))

Answer (score 0):

abstract.js

```
function abstractClass(construct_options){{

}
```

someObject.js

```
someObject.prototype = new abstractClass();
someObject.prototype.foo = function(){


}
```

otherObject.js

```
otherObject.prototype = new abstractClass();
otherObject.prototype.toe = function(){


}
```

further you can do like this:

```
var a = new someObject();
var b = new otherObject();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can move all functions into separate files and add them to the prototyp of your application.

**file initialize.js:**

```
function initialize () {
    this.displayArray =  new Array();
}
```

**file initilize.js:**

```
function() Application{
    this.userOptions = new Array();
    this.query = '';
    this.status = false;
    this.initialize();
}

Application.prototype.initialize = initialize;
```

This solution will polute your global names spaces with all the function from the external files. So if its a larger project you should start to use and AMD solution like [requirejs](http://requirejs.org/):

**file initialize.js:**

```
define(function () {
    return function () {
        this.displayArray =  new Array();
    }
})
```

**file initilize.js:**

```
define(['initialize'], function (initialize) {
    function() Application{
        this.userOptions = new Array();
        this.query = '';
        this.status = false;
        this.initialize();
    }

    Application.prototype.initialize = initialize;
    return Application;
})
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, you helped me so much and I love the idea of using nameSpaces.

Answer (score 0):

You could define the application 'class' in one file, then use prototype to add each function in separate files, e.g.

```
var application = function () { };

application.prototype.method1 = function (arg1) {
window.alert(arg1);
}

var a = new application();
a.method1('Hello, World!');
```